# The \n isn't working in python and tried and alternate method and doesn't give the same results

Tags: python

I am trying to write to a json file and its doing all that but when I do this code it rights it to the file twice and the \n if I += just shows as text I try the triple parenthesis and that just tabs it. It also writes  the information twice for some reason I dont know why.

```
import json

log_file = open('xdate_debug.log', 'r')

json_file_name = 'HOSTANDIPINFO.json'
# Loop through each line in the log file
for line in log_file:
    # Check if the line contains the word "hostname"
    if 'Hostname:' in line:
        # If the line contains the word "hostname", print it to the console
        print(line.strip())
        text = line.strip()

log_file.close()

log_file = open('xdate_debug.log', 'r')

for line in log_file:
    # Check if the line contains the word "hostname"
    if 'Found controller' in line:
        # If the line contains the word "hostname", print it to the console
        print(line.strip())

        text += """
        """
        text += text + line.strip()
        with open(json_file_name, 'w') as json_file:
            json.dump(text, json_file)

log_file.close()
# Close the log file
```

The output is 3 lines it prints in the console fine

in the json file it should be

```
line1
line2
line 3
```

instead it's

```
line1 line 1 line 2 line 2 line 3 line 3
```

Comment: What you are doing doesn't make a lot of sense. Why use `json` here? You are just writing a *string*?

Answer (score 0):

In the line

```
text += text + line.strip()
```

you are basically doing this:

```
text = text + text + line.strip()
```

Thats why you get duplicates

Comment: Yeah I am derping sorry :( I figured out the other issues though :D

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are appending `text` to `line.strip()`, which results in duplication. Additionally, you are writing to the JSON file inside the `for` loop, so the script writes to the file multiple times. You should first obtain **all** the data you need to write to the JSON file, and write it after the loop. Try something like:

```py
lines = []

for line in log_file:
    if 'Hostname:' in line:
        print(line.strip())
        text = line.strip()

    if 'Found controller' in line:
        lines.append(line.strip())

log_file.close()

text += '\n\n'.join(lines)

with open(json_file_name, 'w') as json_file:
    json.dump(text, json_file)
```

Comment: why would you use JSON here?? It doesn't make any sense

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga tbh I don't really know - it's what he was using in his original script

Answer (score 0):

```
import json

# Open the log file for reading
with open("xdate_debug.log", "r") as log_file:
    # Initialize an empty list to store matching lines
    matching_lines = []
    # Loop over each line in the file
    for line in log_file:
        # Check if the line contains "Hostname:" and "Found controller"
        if "Hostname:" in line or "Found controller" in line:
            # Add the matching line to the list
            matching_lines.append(line.strip())

# Define the name of the output JSON file
output_file_name = "HOSTANDIPINFO.json"

# Open the output file for writing
with open(output_file_name, "w") as output_file:
    # Loop over each matching line and write it to the output file as a separate JSON object
    for line in matching_lines:
        # Create a Python dictionary with a single "line" key and the matching line as the value
        data = line
        # Write the dictionary as a JSON object to the output file, followed by a newline character
        output_file.write(json.dumps(data) + "\n")


print(matching_lines)
```